# Clear Screen Command in C++

Tags: c++, windows-7, mingw, codeblocks

I want to clear the screen after user enters some numbers in C++. I'm programming in console application mode.

so how to do it? My OS is win7 and My IDE is CodeBlocks and the Compiler is MingW...

Comment: what about clrscr(); method????

Comment: include your os and IDE in the question because the answer depends on both

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends of your OS,
If you use linux:

```
system("clear");
```

If you use windows:

```
system("cls");
```

but this make your application lees portable, it's preferable to do

```
cout << string(50, '\n');
```

this line will print lines to seem like the terminal was 'cleared'.

A good article about that problem:
http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/4z18T05o/

Comment: 50? that is horrible algorithm!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `clrscr()` defined in `conio.h`.

[Ways to clear screen the output screen](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1031963460&id=1043284385).

Comment: For using Clrscr which header I should use?

Comment: I google before asking, and come here. Google doesn't create content, it helps you find content by indexing it

Comment: Oh did you? and you didnt fnd any relevant answers? Try checking this  https://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=how+to+clear+screen+in+a+console+c%2B%2B+application

Answer (score 2):

you can try system methods  E.g.  system("CLS");

Answer (score 1):

link the conio.h in your compiler. I forgot how to do that. if you will use clear screen repeatedly put this function.

```
enter code here
void clrscr()
{
  system("cls");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's what Microsoft has to say about clearing a console:

```
#include <windows.h>

void cls( HANDLE hConsole )
{
   COORD coordScreen = { 0, 0 };    // home for the cursor
   DWORD cCharsWritten;
   CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
   DWORD dwConSize;

   // Get the number of character cells in the current buffer.

   if( !GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( hConsole, &csbi ))
   {
      return;
   }

   dwConSize = csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y;

   // Fill the entire screen with blanks.

   if( !FillConsoleOutputCharacter( hConsole,        // Handle to console screen buffer
                                    (TCHAR) ' ',     // Character to write to the buffer
                                    dwConSize,       // Number of cells to write
                                    coordScreen,     // Coordinates of first cell
                                    &cCharsWritten ))// Receive number of characters written
   {
      return;
   }

   // Get the current text attribute.

   if( !GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( hConsole, &csbi ))
   {
      return;
   }

   // Set the buffer's attributes accordingly.

   if( !FillConsoleOutputAttribute( hConsole,         // Handle to console screen buffer
                                    csbi.wAttributes, // Character attributes to use
                                    dwConSize,        // Number of cells to set attribute
                                    coordScreen,      // Coordinates of first cell
                                    &cCharsWritten )) // Receive number of characters written
   {
      return;
   }

   // Put the cursor at its home coordinates.

   SetConsoleCursorPosition( hConsole, coordScreen );
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE hStdout;

    hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    cls(hStdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> system("cls");
>
> > Brilliant. So what happens if I replace the Windows cls with my own malicious cls? You've just given me control, thanks! This is what's called a back door, and you left it wide open by using an insecure technique.

Source: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/76934/how-do-i-clear-my-screen-in-c.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to output '\f' (corresponding to the ASCII form feed character, code 12, which is used by line printers to eject a page, and recognized by some common terminals and emulators as a clear screen).

That won't work on Windows.

```
#ifdef _WIN32
/* windows hack */
#else
std::cout << '\f' std::flush;
#endif
```